# Configure Aurelia Project using Visual Studio

Tags: aurelia

I know it's very new, but I'd like to create a prototype using aurelia with Visual Studio.  VS support is in the hopper, but the current documentation is based on node.js et al.  Based on the existing documentation, I haven't a clue.  I'm hoping I can get some guidance...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are looking for, but you can check out this github Aurelia project, using Typescript and VS 2013. It still makes use of gulp and jspm but with the VS Taskrunner extension.

https://github.com/AshleyGrant/aspnet-skeleton-navigation

There is now a default project supporting VS 2015: 
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation

Comment: I guess I need node.js after all.  Shows what I know.  Anyway, this project is very useful.

Comment: I did not know about this TaskRunner, seems great for stealing tools (and using packages) from NodeJS stack :)))

Answer (score 4):

There are several sample Aurelia Visual Studio solutions contained here: [aurelia typescript samples](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript)

These samples use a javascript bundle (also created as part of the repo), so no gulp is needed.

Warning - these are samples and are not polished.

Comment: Mike suppose we want publish our project on shared hosting and window azure where we don't have Nodejs installed . That means our Aurelia application will not work ?

Comment: you should be able to run the projects here https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript without nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

- Download and Install Node.js 
  Then create a Visual Studio project and on the toplevel of that folder execute for>
- Install Gulp for build automation

> npm install -g gulp

- Install JSPM as client-side package manager

> npm install -g jspm

- Install Git for Windows and configure Github

> jspm registry config github

- Generate a skeleton project by using Yeoman

> npm install -g yo generator-aurelia

then enter

> yo aurelia

- Install Plugins needed by gulp

> npm install

- Install JSPM dependencies of the package
  manifest

> jspm install -y

- Gulp Watch to run

> gulp watch

all from this tutorial> [Tutaurelia.net](http://tutaurelia.net/2015/06/05/part-5-configuring-and-getting-started-with-aurelia/)

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) would work well with Aurelia, I had a play around with the demo and the skeleton app and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this https://github.com/BoudewijnvanVeen/Aurelia-Typescript-Skeleton-4VS

Lets you run an Aurelia application using Visual Studio with Typescript debugging.doesnt use Gulp

Comment: Why has this been voted down? It answers the question. Is the quality of the sample code so poor it merits a spanking? If so why didn't you say so?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run Aurelia Visual Studio Project without Nodejs .

https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#just-use-it---visual-studio-using-requirejs-amd-module-loader
[image]

But it not able to find "http://lcoalhost:6260/aurelia/core-js/client/core.js".

that means we need make sure that NodeJs installed on server with this command

run node r.js -o name=aurelia-bundle-manifest baseUrl=. mainConfigFile=main-config.js out=aurelia-bundle.min.js

Need to create bundling into server like

https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#bundling

Comment: that file is in the repository: https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/tree/master/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/aurelia/core-js/client.  when you run from visual studio, do you start at http://localhost:6260?

Comment: this should work fine without node.js.  if you post more info we can trouble shoot.