# Run Aurelia Framework without NodeJs and JSPM

Tags: .net, aurelia

I am learning Aurelia Framework. I seen its document given example in NodeJs and JSPM.

But I don't have NodeJs and JSPM. I am from .Net background.

Its possible to run Aurelia Framework without install NodeJS.

I want run Aurelia Framework just like add  tag and add CDN link.
Its possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write and execute Aurelia in Visual Studio without NodeJS or JSPM.  Here is a port of the Aurelia skeleton-navigation to TypeScript which uses a bundle of the Aurelia AMD Libraries.  You should be able to clone the repo and then load this up in Visual Studio and run the app (using Chrome) without any other action.

https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#just-use-it---visual-studio-using-requirejs-amd-module-loader

if you are interested, [here are the details on how the bundle is created](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#bundling)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes - you can write and execute Aurelia on Visual studio.
No - you will still have to install all the supporting modules (such as NodeJS and JSPM) on your set up machine.

To play around with Aurelia on Visual Studio (2013) try this set up. 
[Demo Navigation app in VS](https://github.com/AshleyGrant/aspnet-skeleton-navigation) Follow the set up instruction to install the modules.

This demo was written with an older version Typescript.  If you update the Typescript to the latest version (v1.4), then the template strings will work.

Comment: in theory, you could customize your aurelia deployment to be independent of node and jspm. but i don't think anyone has gone down that rabbit hole yet.

Comment: I believe Nodejs is there to compile and package using 6to5 and JSPM.  Once the target is created, then there is no need for Nodejs.

Comment: Yes I tried to run Aurelia Visual Studio Project without NodeJs , Its not working.  See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200469/configure-aurelia-project-using-visual-studio/28470148#28470148

Comment: you dont need to use JSPM