# How to get an TS project to use and compile with stand-alone Aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia, typescript2.0

I have projects that use typescript that we compile with tsc.exe. It's come to the point that I'm considering a native TS based ria framework like Aurelia. Our build stack is fairly static and well controlled, so no node. I'm not really clear on how to move forward. I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384199/run-aurelia-framework-without-nodejs-and-jspm) but that is rather old and doesn't seem to work/apply anymore.

So exactly what must I do to get on-boarded to Aurelia from download to "hello world" without using extraneous build tools?

Note: For what it's worth we don't use VS, but Komodo and a little bit of VS.Code.

Comment: What module loader are you planning to use?

Comment: We've had descent results with SystemJS

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend that you switch to VS code as it is a great editor for TypeScript and Aurelia.
2. You can use Aurelia CLI (see [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/1)) to do compile, pack and serve your code.

Comment: 1) it was on the table but we have KIDE setup for debugging our projects (mostly php). VSC does not seem to do that well yet 2) How exactly would the CLI work without a js runtime?

Comment: 2) you're right, I guess I did not understand your question right. may I ask what is the issue with installing node.js on your build environment?

Comment: New runtimes (like node or ruby) need to have a strong case for inclusion as a dependency as, among other reasons, they might need to go as far as a client. With few exceptions, only the likes of c#, php, or Java work because "our whole application is written in it" is the only acceptable reason. Simple tools (and even tsc.exe is a little gray) are easier because they have a small integration footprint (less they can interact with, easier to keep up to date, etc.)

Comment: well... I guess it is a matter of perspective to what a footprint of a node.js installation (or even just the runtime) has, especially if it is only required for build purposes. I will leave the contemplation to you. In any case, I wish you luck in finding your solution. I think with Aurelia you are quite limited to using node at this point.Though you should be able to pack all the build dependency into one maintainable folder.