# Aurelia Project Setup has error out of the box, what's the fix?

Tags: javascript, windows, installation, aurelia

I have followed the simple step-by-step instructions in the Basic Aurelia Project Setup guide. But starting the index.html in a browser results in the config-esnext.js file throwing: "JavaScript runtime error: 'System' is undefined". This is on the first line: System.config({...

The browser's output window has this to say:
"Could not find file 'C:\Users\Bruce\Dropbox\Projects Aurelia\Basic Aurelia Setup\scripts\system.js.map'..Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1 in http://localhost:56477/scripts/config-esnext.js"

Is there some "map" configuration missing from the simple instructions? I am running the project from Visual Studio 2015, configured for Esnext.

Comment: I had an issue similar to this. It usually has something to do with where you ran your jspm, gulp, yeoman, aurelia commands. You need to be very aware of how the folder structure works, and where the config files/ virtual folders need to be.

Comment: Additionally, I would not do this in a dropbox folder. I'm not sure how all the permissions work, but it could be something to check into.

Comment: The Basic Aurelia Project Setup guide only has me create a few js files and then start up IISExpress and serve index.htm. No  jspm, gulp, yeoman, etc commands were used.

Comment: Then you are looking at the wrong guide. http://tutaurelia.net/2015/06/05/part-5-configuring-and-getting-started-with-aurelia/ . I forget which one I did, but this looks similar.

Comment: Alternately, here is a stack over flow post about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200469/configure-aurelia-project-using-visual-studio

Comment: Why don't you use aurelia-cli? It's so much easier, and SystemJS is being phased out in favor of it.

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I will try the Part 5 tutorial. And I'll look at the cli too. Thanks both.

Answer (score 0):

The comments to the original question have some good discussion going. But for the sake of providing an "answer" for others to find, here goes.

Without seeing your `index.html` file, I can't determine *exactly* what is going on. But the error you're seeing is happening because `System` isn't defined on the window. This will happen if you haven't loaded up System yet. You need to make sure that your `index.html` file loads up SystemJS *first*, then you load up your config file.
You can see in the skeleton project's `index.html` [found here](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/1.0.1/skeleton-esnext/index.html#L24), that `system.js` is loaded before we bring in the configuration file. Here is an example of a proper `index.html` using SystemJS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <span>Loading...</span>    

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As an alternative, the CLI helps get a skeleton project up quickly (it doesn't include a navigation example, it is a bare-bones skeleton). It uses RequireJS however, but we have plans to support other module loaders (such as SystemJS) down the road.